# Helix Toolkit WPF, change camera vector on mouse click

Tags: c#, xaml, helix-3d-toolkit

I have a view in helix with 4 boxes, when I click one of them I want the camera to view that box. My code works fine but as soon as I scroll a little with the mouse wheel (to zoom in/out), then it is no longer possible to click and view a box like I want. The same mouse click event is firing and I don't notice any difference when debugging. Just the camera is not moved. The scrolling messes everything up somehow but I don't know how and what to do. EDIT: Also right clicking and moving the camera that way causes the same error.

```
<helix:HelixViewport3D x:Name="View"
                       Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Visuals}"
                       ShowCameraInfo="False"
                       ShowCoordinateSystem="True"
                       ShowViewCube="False"
                       ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="False"
                       ModelUpDirection="0,1,0"
                       DefaultCamera="{Binding DefCamera}"
                       >

    <helix:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
        <PerspectiveCamera FieldOfView="61"
                           LookDirection="{Binding LookDirection}"
                           Position="{Binding CameraPosition}"
                           UpDirection="0,1,0" />
    </helix:HelixViewport3D.Camera>

    <!-- Selecting is done by first deselecting all boxes on mouse down
         then selecting the correct one on mouse up -->

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="DeselectAll" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

</helix:HelixViewport3D>
```

This `UIElement` class defines a transparent box around the original box. When clicked, it runs selectionChanged action in the parent class. That action calculates a new Position and Lookdirection which are bound in XAML above.

```
public class InteractiveBoxVisual3D : System.Windows.UIElement3D
{
    public int SensorID { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    private System.Action SelectionChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mat">Matrix which defines the position and rotation</param>
    /// <param name="box">Box defines the box size in XYZ</param>
    /// <param name="sensorID">Sensor ID of the sensor</param>
    /// <param name="selectionChanged">Action run when box is selected or deselected</param>
    public InteractiveBoxVisual3D(Matrix3D mat, Box3D box, int sensorID, System.Action selectionChanged)
    {
        SensorID = sensorID;
        IsSelected = false;
        SelectionChanged = selectionChanged;
        Material material = MaterialHelper.CreateMaterial(Colors.Transparent);
        MeshBuilder meshBuilder = new MeshBuilder();

        Vector3D VX = new Vector3D(mat.M11, mat.M12, mat.M13);
        Vector3D VY = new Vector3D(mat.M21, mat.M22, mat.M23);

        // This selection box is larger by this amount, to avoid graphical errors
        int margin = 10;

        meshBuilder.AddBox(new Point3D(mat.OffsetX, mat.OffsetY, mat.OffsetZ), VX, VY, box.Lx + margin, box.Wy + margin, box.Hz + margin);
        Visual3DModel = new GeometryModel3D(meshBuilder.ToMesh(), material);
    }

    public void Select()
    {
        GeometryModel3D box = Visual3DModel as GeometryModel3D;
        box.Material = MaterialHelper.CreateMaterial(Colors.White);
        IsSelected = true;
        SelectionChanged.Invoke();
    }

    public void DeSelect()
    {
        GeometryModel3D box = Visual3DModel as GeometryModel3D;
        box.Material = MaterialHelper.CreateMaterial(Colors.Transparent);
        IsSelected = false;
        SelectionChanged.Invoke();
    }

    // There is a simulaneous mouse DOWN event which runs DeselectAll()
    protected override void OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonState.Released)
        {
            Select();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Viewport3D.LookAt or Camera.LookAt function to manipulate your camera directly.

Comment: I tried and accessing the viewport3d object from codebehind does work better. However the architecture im working in prohibits that, we use bindings. And binding from xaml to a viewport3d or cameracontroller can't be done. Also, since my solution only stops working when the camera is moved or zoomed, i feel that it shouldn't need alot of rework.

Comment: You can use Camera.LookAt and create a camera in your viewmodel.

Comment: No, I can't bind to a Camera. System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Camera' property of type 'HelixViewport3D'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.'
When I write <helix:HelixViewport3D Name="HVP"
                           ...
                           Camera="{Binding PCAM}"
                           >